# ORMLite's iterator forgets all the data after hasNext() == false

Tags: iterator, ormlite

code sample:

```
//...
CloseableIterator<Order> iterator = dao.iterator();

iterator.first(); // Object
iterator.current(); // Object

iterator.hasNext(); // false (only 1 record in table "Order")

iterator.current(); // null (?!)
iterator.first(); // null (?!!)
```

Also, iterator.previous() returns null too (if more than 1 record, ofc).

How to forbid ORMLite's SelectIterator to forget my data after calling hasNext() on the last record?..

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code of ORMLite, it is a normal undocumented unchangeable behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this myself.  We're using ORMLite on Android and were able to use methods available on the DatabaseResults member, available by calling:

```
iterator.getRawResults()
```

You'll have to cast it to the appropriate type before being able to do things like safely check count etc. (depending on whether or not they are available in your particular implementation)